# How to replace a particular json with another json in react

Tags: reactjs

I am using github api and got the content of manifest.json file.

I am trying to add some new json lines into that existing json folder.

This the old content which is existing

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

this is the expected content output , after adding those new json contents it should look like this

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "maskable.png",
      "sizes": "280x280",
      "type":"image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "logo256.png",
        "sizes": "256x256",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "logo348.png",
        "sizes": "348x348",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "logo512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

I tried string.replace but it is not working

```
let newContent = oldContent.replace(`{"src": "favicon.ico","sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16","type": "image/x-icon"},`,  
`{"src": "logo256.png","sizes": "256x256","type": "image/png"},{"src": "logo348.png","sizes": "348x348",         "type": "image/png"},`);
```

Comment: Can you please mention the specific fields that you're trying to replace?

Comment: Instead of replacing, if new JSON fields can be added to icons that is also fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read data from json file first.After reading data you can use `JSON.parse(filedata)` method to convert your data to java script object.
After converting you can replace data by manipulating JavaScript object.After Replacing the data you have to stringfy the java script objects using `JSON.stringfy(data)`.And last step to write it again in file.

Comment: after converting the string content to a js object, I am able to access icons from the content seperately. Now ,how to add extra json fields inside that icons?

Comment: You can add new attribute/data into java script object using java script object manipulation techniques. e.g in case of you want to add new icon in icons. `data.icons=[...data.icons,{src:"new",size:"new",type:"new"}]`.I am using spread opreater to insert data you can choose  any technique. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manipulating strings, you can convert it to an object and add values:

```
var json_object = JSON.parse(`{"src": "favicon.ico"...`);

json_object.icons = "{
  "src": "maskable.png",
  "sizes": "280x280",
  "type":"image/png",
  "purpose": "any maskable"
}"
```